# Forwarding app preprocessor information to static library

Tags: c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I'm developing a static library in XCode within a test app. I can work on the test app and library simultaneously by dragging the library project into the test app project and then adding the library to the test app project build phases . .

[image]

Is there any way to forward preprocessor flags from the test app to the library? For example, I have tried adding the flag `MY_DEBUG_FLAG` to the test app project, and then in my static lib header I have added . . .

```
#if defined(MY_DEBUG_FLAG)
#define MY_DEBUG_FLAG_USED
#endif
```

...however, the `#ifdef MY_DEBUG_FLAG_USED` blocks in the library are ignored. I could always add the flag to both library and app projects, but this is a nasty bit of repetition that I'd like to avoid if at all possible. I hope my goal is clear, and I'm very open to a completely different idiom if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since preprocessing by definition is performed before compilation, there's no way to pass preprocessor flags to a compiled library.

What you can do is add a set of variables to the library which it can inspect at runtime, and set these to the relevant values in your application, or let the library provide functions for enabling or disabling different aspects of it.